# Applying Animation to specific parts of a humanoid model

Tags: unity, animation, mecanim

I have imported a humanoid character from [AutoDesk Character Generator](https://charactergenerator.autodesk.com/) into Unity. Once you specify that you want the character for Unity, a humanoid skeleton in integrated, in order to use MecAnim.

I also have a plug-in that applies the user's motion data to this character and animates it. Because the plug-in is free and open-source, I am trying to apply the motion data to different MecAnim bones, to see if I can do so.

By the way, by "motion data" I am referring to 2 arrays: one that contains positions and one that contains orientations of a number of joints and bones. So, I can access these `Vector3` and `Quaternion` data...

Is it enough to just apply, for example, the left foot's orientations to the right foot, or do I need to also do it with positions, in order to inter-change the animations/motions/movements of these 2 limbs?

This is the method I have written so far:

```
public void swapLimbsPosRot(Vector3[] positionsArray, Quaternion[] rotationsArray)
{
            Vector3 tempPos = positionsArray[16];
            positionsArray[16] = positionsArray[20];
            positionsArray[20] = tempPos;

            Quaternion tempRot = rotationsArray[16];
            rotationsArray[16] = rotationsArray[20];
            rotationsArray[20] = tempRot;                    
}
```

But it doesn't work, because when I apply it to my array of transforms before updating, severe jitters show there is a fighting going on between MecAnim and my motion capture device' incoming motion data, but for now I am just wondering:

**If you wanted to swap the animations/movements/motions of 2 similar MecAnim parts, what would you do? What would you swap? How would you go about it?**

p.s. Of course, first I tried swapping the mecanim bones (right & left feet) but that turned out silly, as the "actual" feet of my MecAnim character had been swapped!

Some code, showing how the swapping and updating are done now, hoping someone could please help me find the cause of the jitters.

```
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3[] latestPositions;
        Quaternion[] latestOrientations;

        if (mvnActors.getLatestPose(out latestPositions, out latestOrientations))
        {
                // If this variable is set to true, then do the swapping.
                if (swapLimbs)
                {
                    swapLimbsPosRot(latestOrientations);
                }

                // Update both the pose and the model, using the delayed data.
                updateMvnActor(currentPose, latestPositions, latestOrientations);
                updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);             
        }               
    }


    /// Swap the rotations of different mimicking limbs; e.g. LeftHand = 16 & RightHand = 20
    public void swapLimbsPosRot(Quaternion[] rotationsArray)
    {
        float tempRotY = rotationsArray[16].y;
        rotationsArray[16].y = rotationsArray[20].y;
        rotationsArray[20].y = tempRotY;

        float tempRotZ = rotationsArray[16].z;
        rotationsArray[16].z = rotationsArray[20].z;
        rotationsArray[20].z = tempRotZ;
    }
```

The motion data that comes in is always the latest positions and orientations from the device, so Update modify them and then apply them to the character to animate it. So, for example, in my Update, I get the latest pose (i.e. the latest positions and orientations) and then I swap the orientations of left and right hands, but the jitters are severe...

Comment: The animation looks fine, without jitter, when you don't apply your script? I'm not too familiar with quaternions, but usually when mirroring animation between two limbs, you only want to mirror certain axis/values. For example, when mirroring the foot position, you only wish to mirror the x or z axis (depending on your forward axis). A dicussion on the subject [link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/349626-mirroring-a-quaternion/)

Comment: @amorten Hi, Thanks for your comment, I was giving up hope on this... The animation looks fine, without jitters, when I don't apply the _swapping function_. Thanks for the link. I will go through it today. I will leave another comment later. Cheers

Comment: @amorten Hi again, your link was a very informative set of posts. But because the jitters are very bad, I cannot see the effects of manipulating individual axes. I will add some more code to my question (in an edit) so please see if you can help me find the cause of the jitters. Many thanks